# incomplete result in table scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to scrape http://bifr.nic.in/asp/list.asp this page with beautifulsoup and get the table from it.
Following is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
base_url = "http://bifr.nic.in/asp/list.asp"

page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table",{"class":"forumline"})
tr = table.find_all("tr")
for rows in tr:
    print(rows.get_text())
```

It shows no error, but when i execute it i am only able to get first row of content from the table.

```
List of Companies

Case
            No
Company
            Name









 359  2000   A & F OVERSEAS LTD.





 359  2000   A & F OVERSEAS LTD.
 359  2000   A & F OVERSEAS LTD.
```

This is the result i am getting. I can't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get all the data from that table:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = urlopen("http://bifr.nic.in/asp/list.asp")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
table = soup.select_one("table.forumline")
for items in table.select("tr")[4:]:
    data = ' '.join([item.get_text(" ",strip=True) for item in items.select("td")])
    print(data)
```

Partial Output:

```
359 2000 A & F OVERSEAS LTD.
99 1988 A B C PRODUCTS LTD.
103 1989 A INFRASTRUCTURE LTD.
3 2006 A V ALLOYS LTD.
13 1988 A V J WIRES LTD.
```

Comment: Wow! How you did that? like it gives all the rows with proper formatting. Can you explain in short

Comment: Glad to help @sandy. First off, `html5lib` fixes the broken html. What `.get_text(" ",strip=True)` does is strip the unwanted spaces and `"".join()` makes list into regular string. Check out the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the page code contains some errors in html markup, try use html5lib instead of html.parser, but before you need install it:

```
pip install html5lib


soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
```

Comment: That was not the question. Question specifically says `incomplete result`.

Comment: With this also i am getting only 359  2000   A & F OVERSEAS LTD. in result. but yes just in proper format.